# retrieve checked option after result is displayed in multi select jquery

Tags: jquery, select

The check box selection at the drop down list is NOT retained after the result is being populated.

sample code

```js
$("#DDLCheck").multiselect({
    header: "Select Options Below"
});

var array_of_checked_values = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
});
```

i want to show checked option after the search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (_all != null && _all != "" && _all != undefined && _all == "ALL") {
    $("select").multiselect("widget").find("input:checkbox:eq(0)").trigger("click");
}
```